# click xpath for a dynamic checkbox in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

HTML:

```
input type="checkbox" value="21-22-122-122" id="woWizardDevices_checkboxset_option_21-22-122-122|cb" data-oj-option-id="woWizardDevices_checkboxset_option_21-22-122-122" name="woWizardDevices_checkboxset_21-22-122-122" aria-label="[['Checkbox Select Row ' + row.item.data.id]]" class="oj-checkbox oj-component oj-enabled oj-component-initnode oj-selected" data-oj-internal="" placeholder="" data-oj-tabmod="NaN" tabindex="-1" xpath="1"
```

The ids keep on updating

I have tried:

```
List<WebElement> AllCheckboxes = driver.findElements(
            By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and starts-with(@id,'woWizardDevices_checkboxset_option_21-22')]"));

    int size = AllCheckboxes.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        AllCheckboxes.get(i).click();
        break;

    }
```

but it fails.

Comment: Could you try with a contains instead of starts-with?

Comment: Please give more detailed explanation than *it fails*. And what is the purpose of the loop here?